# jackson mapping nested hashmap to nested pojo class in java

Tags: java, jackson, pojo, objectmapper

I have a nested java map like this
inputMap: {jobId={EndpointReference={ReferenceParameters={ResourceURI=http://schemas.com/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/Job, SelectorSet={Selector=[JID_502260561923, root/im]}}, Address=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous}}, returncode=4096, messageId=null, arguments=null, message=null}
which I want to map to java pojo and here is my pojo classes.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class DMResponseMapper {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    public static class GetSysConfigDMResponseMapper {
        @JsonProperty("jobId")
        private EndpointReferenceMapper endpointReferenceMapper;
        private Integer returnCode;
        private String messageId;
        private String arguments;
        private String message;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @ToString
        public static class EndpointReferenceMapper {
            @JsonProperty("ReferenceParameters")
            private ReferenceParametersMapper referenceParametersMapper;
            @JsonProperty("Address")
            private String address;

                @Getter
                @Setter
                @ToString
                public static class ReferenceParametersMapper {

                    @JsonProperty("ResourceURI")
                    private String resourceURI;

                    @JsonProperty("SelectorSet")
                    private SelectorSetMapper selectorSetMapper;

                    @Getter
                    @Setter
                    @ToString
                    public static class SelectorSetMapper {

                        @JsonProperty("Selector")
                        private List<String> selector;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but objectMapper.convertValue(inputMap, GetSysConfigDMResponseMapper.class) is NOT mapping the nested classes.. just the top level fields.
My objectMapper is instantiated like this:

```
static {
objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

}

Response Object is :

DMResponseMapper.GetSysConfigDMResponseMapper(endpointReferenceMapper=DMResponseMapper.GetSysConfigDMResponseMapper.EndpointReferenceMapper(referenceParametersMapper=null, address=null), returnCode=4096, messageId=null, arguments=null, message=null)

Can anyone please suggest, what is wrong here?

Upon debugging this is what I see:
Converted endpointReferenceMapper to type Object.

```
DMResponseMapper.GetSysConfigDMResponseMapper(endpointReferenceMapper={EndpointReference={ReferenceParameters={ResourceURI=http://schemas.com/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/Job, SelectorSet={Selector=[JID_502318722705, root/dcim]}}, Address=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous}}, returnCode=4096, messageId=null, arguments=null, message=null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DMResponseMapper` pojo needs to follow the structure of your source data more closely.

Your source `Map` object has the following structure, based on the info in the question:

```
inputMap: 
{
  jobId={
    EndpointReference={
      ReferenceParameters={
        ResourceURI=http://schemas.com/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/Job, 
        SelectorSet={
          Selector=[JID_502260561923, root/im]
        }
      }, 
      Address=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous
    }
  }, 
  returncode=4096, 
  messageId=null, 
  arguments=null, 
  message=null
}
```

So, I adapted your `DMResponseMapper` pojo class to more closely map to that structure - and I changed the nested class names as well. Here is a summary of the nested classes with their fields for your data:

```
//
// NOT the actual class - just an overview of the structure!
//
class DMResponseMapper {

    private JobId jobId;
    private Integer returncode;
    private Object messageId;
    private Object arguments;
    private Object message;

    class JobId {

        private EndpointReference endpointReference;

        class EndpointReference {

            private ReferenceParameters referenceParameters;
            private String address;

            class ReferenceParameters {

                private String resourceURI;
                private SelectorSet selectorSet;

                class SelectorSet {
                    private List<String> selector = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gave me the following, when fleshed out with annotations and getters/setters:

```
//
// Here is the actual class, based on the above structure.
//
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.util.List;

public class DMResponseMapper {

    @JsonProperty("jobId")
    private JobId jobId;
    @JsonProperty("returncode")
    private Integer returncode;
    @JsonProperty("messageId")
    private Object messageId;
    @JsonProperty("arguments")
    private Object arguments;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private Object message;

    @JsonProperty("jobId")
    public JobId getJobId() {
        return jobId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("jobId")
    public void setJobId(JobId jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("returncode")
    public Integer getReturncode() {
        return returncode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("returncode")
    public void setReturncode(Integer returncode) {
        this.returncode = returncode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("messageId")
    public Object getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("messageId")
    public void setMessageId(Object messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("arguments")
    public Object getArguments() {
        return arguments;
    }

    @JsonProperty("arguments")
    public void setArguments(Object arguments) {
        this.arguments = arguments;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public Object getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public void setMessage(Object message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public static class JobId {

        @JsonProperty("EndpointReference")
        private EndpointReference endpointReference;

        @JsonProperty("EndpointReference")
        public EndpointReference getEndpointReference() {
            return endpointReference;
        }

        @JsonProperty("EndpointReference")
        public void setEndpointReference(EndpointReference endpointReference) {
            this.endpointReference = endpointReference;
        }

        public static class EndpointReference {

            @JsonProperty("ReferenceParameters")
            private ReferenceParameters referenceParameters;
            @JsonProperty("Address")
            private String address;

            @JsonProperty("ReferenceParameters")
            public ReferenceParameters getReferenceParameters() {
                return referenceParameters;
            }

            @JsonProperty("ReferenceParameters")
            public void setReferenceParameters(ReferenceParameters referenceParameters) {
                this.referenceParameters = referenceParameters;
            }

            @JsonProperty("Address")
            public String getAddress() {
                return address;
            }

            @JsonProperty("Address")
            public void setAddress(String address) {
                this.address = address;
            }

            public static class ReferenceParameters {

                @JsonProperty("ResourceURI")
                private String resourceURI;
                @JsonProperty("SelectorSet")
                private SelectorSet selectorSet;

                @JsonProperty("ResourceURI")
                public String getResourceURI() {
                    return resourceURI;
                }

                @JsonProperty("ResourceURI")
                public void setResourceURI(String resourceURI) {
                    this.resourceURI = resourceURI;
                }

                @JsonProperty("SelectorSet")
                public SelectorSet getSelectorSet() {
                    return selectorSet;
                }

                @JsonProperty("SelectorSet")
                public void setSelectorSet(SelectorSet selectorSet) {
                    this.selectorSet = selectorSet;
                }

                public static class SelectorSet {

                    @JsonProperty("Selector")
                    private List<String> selector = null;

                    @JsonProperty("Selector")
                    public List<String> getSelector() {
                        return selector;
                    }

                    @JsonProperty("Selector")
                    public void setSelector(List<String> selector) {
                        this.selector = selector;
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

This is invoked as follows:

First, some test data:

```
List<String> selector = new ArrayList();
selector.add("JID_502260561923");
selector.add("root/im");

Map<String, Object> selectorSet = new HashMap();
selectorSet.put("Selector", selector);

String resourceURI = "http://schemas.com/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/Job";

Map<String, Object> referenceParameters = new HashMap();
referenceParameters.put("ResourceURI", resourceURI);
referenceParameters.put("SelectorSet", selectorSet);

String address = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous";

Map<String, Object> endpointReference = new HashMap();
endpointReference.put("ReferenceParameters", referenceParameters);
endpointReference.put("Address", address);

Map<String, Object> jobId = new HashMap();
jobId.put("EndpointReference", endpointReference);

Map<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap();
inputMap.put("jobId", jobId);
inputMap.put("returncode", 4096);
inputMap.put("messageId", "foo");
inputMap.put("arguments", "bar");
inputMap.put("message", "baz");
```

Note I replaced your `null` values with strings, for testing and demonstration.

Then the code to perform the mapping:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
DMResponseMapper mapper = objectMapper.convertValue(inputMap, DMResponseMapper.class);
```

The resulting `mapper` object contains the test data:

[image]

Comment: Thank You. It was a miss.. couldn't read the nesting so minutely.  Which tool did you use to show the class layout?

Comment: You are welcone. In this case, I formatted the JSON using [JSONlint](https://jsonlint.com/) - which allowed me to see the nesting more clearly. Then I designed the class nesting to follow that structure (just the classes and fields). That was a manual step - but you can use tools such as [JSON Schema to POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to help with that. It's a great tool - especially for complex JSON, but I do then sometimes end up simplifying what it generates for my specific needs. There may be better approaches - I am not a JSON expert.